# How to copy the file while making changes to every line [bol]?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, grep

I need to copy a file, so that a destination file has some specific string on beginning of each line, and it needs to be a bash one liner. So no script and loops, just bol.

bol - bash one liner

I personally need this done with command that uses grep program. I appreciate if you can solve it any way possible, I just don't have that much use of it, if not with grep.

EDIT:  Okay, can't be done with grep, sed is okay.

Comment: `sed` is your friend.

Comment: I have this is as an assignment on my college :D needs to be grep and bol

Comment: What is "bol"??

Comment: bol - bash one liner

Comment: What's bol? never heard of it

Comment: "destination file has some specific string on beginning of each line" OK great ! What strings exactly ?

Comment: If you don't mind the prefix ending in a `:` you can do `grep -H --label=prefix`.

Comment: @richard `grep: unknown option -- label=prefix`. You're assuming he's on Linux. If I was a teacher teaching Unix, I would teach them Unix, not Linux ;-)

Comment: Linux does not have `grep`. Gnu (and other Unixes) has grep. Yes I was using Gnu grep, without it you can not even get close to an answer (using grep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^/specific string/' input >output
```

You said you needed to use `grep`, okay...

```
$ sed 's/^/specific string/' input | grep . >output
```

Comment: haha, that's funny, I meant just grep :)

Comment: @Scarass The `grep` utility will print lines matching a pattern. It is not the tool for the job. Tell that to your teacher. Point them to this post.

Comment: @Scarass Seriously. It's like telling a carpenter to construct a chair using a pencil as a tool.

Comment: I just found I can use sed too, I mean I should use sed, grep doesn't work with it ofcourse, sry, I wasn't aware of it, sry for posting without being informed enough. Thanks.

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm such a carpenter, see my answer. PS: and I'm not Scarass' teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Without `sed` and with GNU `grep`, as requested:

```
grep --label="SPECIFIC STRING" --null -H ^ input_file.txt
```

PS: In case you wonder, no, this is not a serious answer

Comment: Haha, let us laugh together at your unserious question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this (untested):

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/new text at line start\1/g' > file-copy.txt
```

could also work with `awk` instead of `sed`

Comment: sry, forgot to state that it needs to use grep

Comment: Then say it. By the way is this homework, 'cos you won't learn if we do it for you.

Comment: or `<file.txt sed -e 's/\(.*\)/new text at line start\1/g' >file-copy.txt` avoids extra process, and unnecessary use of cat.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for `bash`, specifically, here's a one-liner (although a lengthy one):

```
{ while IFS= read -r line ;do printf "%s %s\n" "SPECIAL" "$line" ; done < input.txt ; [ -n "$line" ] && printf "%s %s\n" "SPECIAL"  "$line" ;  }
```

But of course far shorter way is via `awk`:

```
 awk '{print "SPECIAL ",$0}' input.txt
```